# Create Events with liquibase

Tags: mysql, database, liquibase

I need to know how using liquibase I can define a sets of mysql events.
for instance I have 4 files .sql that i will call from .yaml file, each of this files contain a definition like:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name_1 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 week STARTS '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
    Call call_partition();
END

CREATE EVENT event_name_2 ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 week STARTS '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE
DO
BEGIN
    Call call_partition();
END
..
...
....
```

But once I check if the four event were create using: show events; just show me 1 event created not the 4.

Is there any tag define for create event like for procedure exist ?

```
(createProcedure)...
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how you apply the files, but i guess you use [sqlFile](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql_file.html). For procedural (what your event seems to be like) sql you may need to use the `splitStatements` attribute with false:

> Set to false to not have liquibase split statements on ;'s and GO's. Defaults to true if not set

Comment: Other option is the pure <sql> command </sql>, and in the command section you can add any sql script as you want. More info in the official liquibase [documentation](https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/changes/sql.html)